# Test failure of a playbook with Ansible Molecule

Tags: ansible, molecule

I'm creating a **sudo** role and want to test with Molecule that the role fails if a rule is not correct.

How can we define that we expect the playbook to fail with Molecule?

For example, if I have the following configuration:

```
sudo__entries:
  - name: super_alice
    content: "alice ALL NOPASSWD"
```

The role will fail because `visudo` won't validate the file.

And that's the behavior I want to test.

Comment: I did not yet find a correct way of doing this myself in a satisfying way.  Meanwhile you might be interested in the [`side effect` step](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#side-effect) which is not enabled by default (see [ansible provionner doc](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#id22))

Comment: I found documentation on [this page](https://blog.octo.com/the-wizard-side-effects/) of what is side effect, but is does not help testing the failure of a playbook. I updated my question with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify `converge.yml` to test a failure scenario with a rescue block, using a similar method to this unit testing paradigm:

```java
try {
    foo();
    Assert.fail();
} catch(FooException e) {
    // Caught expected exception from foo()
}
```

An example failure scenario for role `sudo` would have a `converge.yml` that looks something like:

```yaml
---
- name: Does not converge
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: "Include sudo"
          include_role:
            name: "sudo"
          register: expected_failure
        - name: "Check execution halted"
          fail:
            msg: "Execution should stop before this task"
          register: should_not_run
      rescue:
        - assert:
            that:
              - expected_failure is defined
              - should_not_run is not defined
```

You can also supplement this with a `verify.yml` to assert the failure scenario did not leave the host in a broken state.